# Gate/ANNIE when using a corpus with many documents

Tags: nlp, gate

I'm working on a project with the platform GATE using the ANNIE plugin, unfortunately when I try to run the Annie application to a large number of documents GATE freezes and stops working, so I have only to shut him down. 
Is this an issue of my machine? Is there something I can do? Is the only solution to run the application to few files at a time?

Comment: I think its connected with Java memory consumption. But it is hard to guess, you didn't provided any details about it (size of the data - documents, how much memory it has taken in the time of freeze, how much CPU it takes at that time, some messages form the log?).

Comment: You're right, the files are 298, 23.8 MB together. 
The log doesn't give any message, since it freezes and I'm not able to do anything.

Comment: You can try to increase the memory limit:
https://gate.ac.uk/sale/tao/splitch2.html#sec:gettingstarted:launchconfig

Answer (score 0):

You can use serial datastore for the large number of documents. "How to" you can find in GATE manual and some code examples in GATE wiki.